# dimensions of isometries

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I was studying something about isomoteries in space and read that the dimension of translation is 3, rotation is 5,screw is 6, reflection is 3 and etc. What does this mean? How to calculate this?

Answer (score 3):

The very short answer is that it is the *set of translations* is three-dimensionals, etc. One often expresses this by saying that the general translation has three *degrees of freedom*, meaning that three numbers are required to specify a translation. For rotations, it is 5: First a line to rotate about (4 degrees of freedom), then an angle of rotation. The line has 4 degrees of freedom because you need to select a point on the line (3 d.o.f.), then a direction (2 d.o.f.), but now you have overspecified because any point on the line would do, so you subtract one. Similar arguments for the others.

For screw transformations, you need one more degree of freedom: The amount of translation along the line of rotation. For a reflection, you just need to specify a plane, and that takes only tree degrees of freedom.

To be more rigorous, you should study the groups of these transformations as [Lie groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group), which have a well defined notion of dimension.